# Custom user auth with Realm Object Server?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

Based on the Realm Object Server [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#authentication), right now we only have access to a limited set of options when it comes to authenticate users: Google, Facebook, iCloud and 'Password'.

I already have an app where users can choose to register their own accounts, or alternatively go with the Facebook / Google login approach. I'd like to bind realms to my existing users. As far as I can see, I'd need to write a custom authentication plugin to do the integration between my user management service and ROS.

Is this currently possible with Real Object Server? In case the answer is no and any Realm guys are reading this: is this scenario on the roadmap possibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is roadmapped. I can't give you a timeline regarding availability though.

The following two issues are related to this:

- https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/50
- https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/29

Comment: Thanks, that's good to hear, I'll certainly +1 those issues then. I'd guess that many companies with existing custom 'legacy' authentication providers would also need this feature in order to consider integrating Realm Mobile Platform - looking forward to this.